# Duplicate entry during build

Tags: java, android, gradle

I, I have upgraded some old architecture and I am struggling with building it. Compile and gradle sync is OK, but when I try to run Build and Run / assemble I have following error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/view/LayoutInflaterFactory.class

I searched through stackoverflow and google and tried disabling for some dependencies support-v4, but it doesn't help and I don't know how to search through following dependencies tree to resolve it. Already tried for bonuspack, permissionDispatcher.

Have you got any idea?

```
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- project :salesChart
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1 -> 23.4.0
|         +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|         |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0
|         |              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0 -> 25.1.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0 (*)
+--- project :domain
+--- com.android.support:design:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0 -> 25.1.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0
+--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5
+--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
+--- uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.2
+--- com.github.citux:datetimepicker:0.2.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4
+--- joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0
+--- org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0
+--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0-rc2
+--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1
+--- com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2
|    \--- com.google.android:android:2.2.1
|         +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|         +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1
|         |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.0.1
|         |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|         |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3
|         +--- org.khronos:opengl-api:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1
|         +--- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:2.6.2
|         +--- xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c
|         \--- org.json:json:20080701
+--- io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0
|    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.4
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2
+--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
+--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0
|    +--- io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0 -> 1.2.0 (*)
|    +--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0 -> 1.1.4
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0 -> 25.1.0
+--- com.annimon:stream:1.0.5
+--- com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48
|    \--- com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48
+--- com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0 -> 3.3.1
|         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.8.0
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1 -> 2.6.2
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2 (*)
|    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.1 -> 1.1.4
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1 (*)
+--- org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.2
+--- com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:v5.8.1
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
|    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4 -> 2.6.2
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0 -> 1.8.0
|    +--- org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.2
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7
|    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
+--- com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.2.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1
|    +--- com.jakewharton:butterknife-annotations:8.5.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.1.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.6
|    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10
\--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5
     +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.6 (*)
     +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.3.8
     |    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.6 (*)
     |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10
     +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10
     \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.1.4

_PC1LSMReleaseCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- project :salesChart
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1 -> 23.4.0
|         +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|         |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0
|         |              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0 -> 25.1.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0 (*)
+--- project :domain
+--- com.android.support:design:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0 -> 25.1.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0
+--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5
+--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
+--- uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.2
+--- com.github.citux:datetimepicker:0.2.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4
+--- joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0
+--- org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0
+--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0-rc2
+--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1
+--- com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2
|    \--- com.google.android:android:2.2.1
|         +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|         +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1
|         |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.0.1
|         |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|         |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3
|         +--- org.khronos:opengl-api:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1
|         +--- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:2.6.2
|         +--- xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c
|         \--- org.json:json:20080701
+--- io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0
|    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.4
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2
+--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
+--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0
|    +--- io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0 -> 1.2.0 (*)
|    +--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0 -> 1.1.4
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0 -> 25.1.0
+--- com.annimon:stream:1.0.5
+--- com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48
|    \--- com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48
+--- com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0 -> 3.3.1
|         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.8.0
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1 -> 2.6.2
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2 (*)
|    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.1 -> 1.1.4
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1 (*)
+--- org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.2
+--- com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:v5.8.1
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
|    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4 -> 2.6.2
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0 -> 1.8.0
|    +--- org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.2
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7
|    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
+--- com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.2.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1
|    +--- com.jakewharton:butterknife-annotations:8.5.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.1.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.6
|    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10
\--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5
     +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.6 (*)
     +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.3.8
     |    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.6 (*)
     |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10
     +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10
     \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.1.4
```

Comment: obviously becuase com.jakewharton:butterknife because it depends on com.android.support:support-compat

Comment: Thanks, I will try this as soon as I will be at work again :) So I must just exclude support compat from butterknife?

Comment: rather you should use older version of`com.jakewharton:butterknife` which was build with `23.4.0` ... or update all support dependencies to `25.1.0`

Comment: off-topic comment: normally I downvote "Duplicate entry during build" but you at least provide some usefull information to resolve the problem, moreover it's hard to guess which library is causing the problem if you don't track the changes of support library ... but starting from `24.2.0` all binaries are inside `support-compat` and `support-v4` is "empty"(classes.jar contains only BuildConfig.class) and depends on `support-compat` library (you can see it by analyzing the *.pom files)

Comment: @Selvin - this was the source of problem. Thank you :D Downgrading butternife to 8.0.1 resolved my problem

Answer (score -1):

You can try two options for this issue.

1) Try clean entire project under build configuration.

2) Go to source folder under directory and delete build folder. As it is always        generated on running configuration and try run the program.

Comment: This was the first 10 steps I made before asking question here

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your v4 library, you have imported it twice and for different versions, so it creates a mess in the build, since you have for 1 resource in that library, 2 entries (from 2 different versions of the same library).

Searching for all the support libraries in your gradle, some of the project are importing : `com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0` and the rest are using `com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1`.

You need to make all of your gradle dependencies to the same version - either 23.4.0 or 23.1.1

Comment: It's not a problem ... `23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)`  means that all refereneces to `23.1.1` are upgraded to `23.4.0`

Comment: that's not true. you've imported both libraries... thats what the duplication mean. did you try setting the same version on all ?

Comment: *you've imported both libraries* no, he doesn't , he is using `23.4.0` and `23.1.1` came from other dependencies ... but it doesn't matter as all those references are upgraded... also I'm not the one who ask the question ... my comment seems to resolve the problem ... problem is `com.android.support:support-compat` end of story